# What are key differences between Scala and Scala.JS that one needs to know to write portable code?

Tags: scala, scala.js

I am developing a pure Scala application (no Java libraries used) and would like to be able to port it to Scala.JS. What should I keep in mind while writing the Scala code to make sure it will be as easy to convert to Scala.JS as possible?

Comment: If you care about converting it to Scala.js in the future, I suggest you setup your cross-building and cross-testing *right now*. That way, you'll have direct feedback on what works and what doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

scala-js.org contains a [complete list of semantic differences](http://www.scala-js.org/doc/semantics.html). If

- you take these into account,
- don't use any Scala library that doesn't cross compile itself,
- don't use any part of the JDK we don't have

Your library should cross compile just fine.

Note that the last bullet unfortunately applies transitively to the Scala standard library itself (or any cross compiled Scala library). So the only really safe choice is to cross compile and test your library.

Answer (score 0):

One important point that I can think of is

No reflection

> Don't use any methods or functions which depend on refection directly or indirectly

Because reflection does not translate well to js world